# Protecting cron scheduling endpoint on AppEngine (Flexible Environment)

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to get my dataflow job scheduled via `cron.yaml` in an AppEngine flexible environment. This works flawlessly when I leave my endpoint unprotected. However, when trying to [secure the endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#securing_urls_for_cron), I see 403 status responses, even when triggering it from within the TaskQueues interface.

My `app.yaml` looks like this:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
- url: /dataflow/schedule
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  login: admin

runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8

resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 1.3
  disk_size_gb: 10

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Comment: Is it possible, that your account doesn't have permissions to run crons from google console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secure handlers (like login: admin) do not work on App Engine Flexible, that is why the 403.

For securing that handler, you can check the request header "X-AppEngine-Cron" in your app, which is a trusted header only set by traffic coming from App Engine.

Comment: Indeed, a `if (req.getHeader("X-Appengine-Cron").equals("true")) { pipeline.run(); }` does the trick!

Comment: And if I inject that header myself, and call the REST endpoint from outside ? Then I can flood it with requests ?